# Why distance function differentiable for sufficiently smooth boundary?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

Suppose that $\Omega$ is bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $C^k$ boundary. Why is it that for points sufficiently close to the boundary the distance function $d = d( \cdot, \partial \Omega)$ is $C^k$? I can see it is enough to take a small ball around the boundary, and take a $C^k$ function $\psi$ defining the boundary and show that this give me a $C^k$ distance function, then use compactness. But, I don't see how to do this.

Thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose the boundary of $C$ is a $C^k$ $(n-1)$-manifold, let's call it $M$.
Focus on a small neighbourhood of a point $P$ in $M$. If this is small enough then
the part of $M$ in this neighbourhood
has a vector field of unit normals pointing into the inside of $\Omega$.
Call the part of the neighbourhood $M'$ and this vector field $v$.
Then there's a map $\Phi:M'\times\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^n$ with $\Phi(m,t)=m+tv(m)$.
This is $C^k$ and in a neighbourhood of $(P,0)$ it is a diffeomorphism. For a point
$Q$ in $\Omega$ near enough $P$ we can write $Q=\Phi(m,t)$ with $t>0$,
the distance of $Q$ to $M$, and with
$m$ the closest point in $M$ to $Q$. The map $Q\mapsto t$ will then be $C^k$.

Of course, I am sweeping a lot of finicky details under the carpet here....